# Which way is best to solve: $T(n)=5T(n/5) + n\;?$

Tags: notation, asymptotics, computability, recursion

I'm not sure which way is best to solve $$T(n)=5T(n/5)  + n$$
(recursion tree/master method/recurrence?) I would like some assistance, which way is easier and how can I be sure I got the right answer (finding the asymptotic behavior)?

A drill down on a solution will be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that correctly? $T(n/5) + 4T(n/5)$ is just $5T(n/5)$ ;)

Comment: yeah, I'm sure :)

Comment: $$T(5^k)/5^k=T(5^{k-1})/5^{k-1}+1\implies T(5^k)=5^k(k+T(1))$$

Comment: @Did, I'm not sure how is this related? thanks

Comment: Well, this seems to fully solve the recursion, showing that $$T(n)\in\Theta(n\log n).$$

Comment: I'm not sure how you managed to prove that Θ notation. please elaborate

Comment: What is the base case ?

Comment: there is no base case in the question I got, it simply a Q to find the asymptotic time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $T(1)=t$, we find

$$T(5)=5t+5=5(t+1)\\
T(25)=25(t+1)+25=25(t+2)\\
T(125)=125(t+2)+125=125(t+3)\\
T(625)=625(t+3)+625=625(t+4)\\
\cdots\\
T(5^k)=5^k(t+k-1)+5^k=5^k(t+k),$$
or
$$T(n)=n(t+\log_5n)$$
when $n$ is a power of $5$.

---

If you want to check an answer like $\Theta(n\log n)$, the first thing to do is to plug the function into the recurrence:

$$T(n)=n\log(n)\leftrightarrow5\frac n5\log(\frac n5)+n=n\log(n)+n(1-\log 5).$$

As the second term has a lower growth rate, it can be ignored, and the equality holds asymptotically. (Not counting the fact that when base $5$ logarithm is used, the agreement is perfect.)

Note that this method doesn't provide a total guarantee, it can only reveal grossly wrong formulas.

Comment: does that mean that T(n)∈Θ(nlogn)?

Comment: Absolutely, isn't it obvious ?

Comment: Not if you're not a Math guy, I'm just starting :)

Comment: The constant $t$ is "neglectable" in front of the logarithm.